# Help Kevin come out of this mysterious world!

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, homophone

Kevin is stuck in a mysterious world. Your task is to help him find the correct route to get back to Earth.

> He finds the following pieces of paper on the ground.
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Kevin collects these notes and finally reaches the end of the mysterious world. There are three routes - Route 1, Route 2 and Route 3. But *only one* of them will lead him towards Earth.

**Help Kevin find the correct route.**
Good luck!

Hint 1:

> Trigonometry

Comment: I see a homophone tag here. Hmm...

Comment: Didn't copy you bro! Just a coincidence 

Comment: I realize that this may have been done intentionally to suit the puzzle construction, but the word is usually expressed as 'monatomic', not 'monoatomic'.

Comment: I wasn't accusing you! I thought it would be a rebus tag or something with that second paper.

Comment: @Dooper =) There are homophones!

Comment: Related to Ryrpgevpny Ratvarrevat. Isn't it?

Comment: @manoj yeah a little bit. The notation....

Comment: Could be Ebhgr gjb orpnhfr Pbf sbhegl svir?

Comment: I thought it as Electrical engineering because Earth/Ground is an essential part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kevin can get out of the mysterious world using

> Route 2

The first piece of paper depicts that

> Cause = Cos

Second piece of paper gives out an idea that

> It is a 45-degree angle.

Third piece of paper says

> Diatomic is preferred. So 2 cos(45) = 2 x 1/root(2) = root(2)

Comment: Vg'f n inevnoyr erfvfgbe. Ohg qb V unir gb nafjre va grezf bs gur purzvpny/ryrpgevpny inyhrf.